# SQL Query : [ Count the result of a query ]

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to use an sql query in Elasticsearch to count the number of users which match my query

So I am using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT user.name 
FROM "winlogbeat-*" 
WHERE event.category = 'authentication' 
AND event.action = 'logon-failed' GROUP BY user.name
) AS result
```

and the result I get is:

```
|44|
|44|
|44|
|44|
|44|
|44|
```

and it's not at all the expected result.
The expected result is :

```
6
```

Could you help me please to find out what is wrong in my query !
Thanks :)

Comment: I find it hard to believe your `count(*)` query returns more than 1 row.

Comment: Also, the subquery can be simplified as `(select distinct user.name FROM "winlogbeat-*" 
WHERE event.category = 'authentication' 
AND event.action = 'logon-failed')`.

Comment: Now you realize that what you want is `select count(distinct user.name) FROM "winlogbeat-*"  WHERE event.category = 'authentication'  AND event.action = 'logon-failed'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the last query you send to me worked `select count(distinct user.name) FROM "winlogbeat-*"  WHERE event.category = 'authentication'  AND event.action = 'logon-failed'`

Comment: and yes the result of the query I used the first time, has 6 rows result, I don't understand why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery can be simplified as `(select distinct user.name FROM "winlogbeat-*"  WHERE event.category = 'authentication'  AND event.action = 'logon-failed')`.

Now you realize that what you want is

```
select count(distinct user.name)
FROM "winlogbeat-*"
WHERE event.category = 'authentication'  AND event.action = 'logon-failed'
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, I just have a seconde question please... I want make a seconde query to get for exemple the count of the query for each user ... like |user1| |count 2|, |user 2| count 3| .....etc. I am trying the query `select user.name as result_count FROM "winlogbeat-*"  WHERE event.category = 'authentication'  AND event.action = 'logon-failed' GROUP BY user.name` but I don't know  how to add a seconde colomn which receive the count of each user !!

Comment: @abdelhalim, ask a new question. (Several questions in one makes the total a bit too unfocused.)

Comment: Okay, I will do that, Thanks :)